# Header, function definitions, main in different files

Tags: c++, oop

I wanna make a program that's it's going to be in 3 files. "Persona.hpp" "Persona.cpp" "main.cpp" im not sure the way it can be done.

**This is "Persona.hpp"**

```
#ifndef __PERSONA_HPP
#define __PERSONA_HPP
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Persona{
public:
    Persona();
    void setNombre(string N);
    void setFechaNac(string F);
    void setPeso(float P);
    void setEstatura(float E);

    string getNombre(void);
    string getFechaNac(void);
    float getPeso(void);
    float getEstatura(void);

    void mostrarDat(void);
private:
    string nombre;
    string fechaNac;
    float peso;
    float estatura;
};
#endif
```

**"Persona.cpp"**

```
#include "Persona.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

Persona::Persona(){
    nombre = "";
    fechaNac = "";
    peso = estatura = 0;
}
void Persona::setNombre(string N){
    nombre = N;
}
void Persona::setFechaNac(string F){
    fechaNac = F;
}
void Persona::setPeso(float P){
    peso = (P>1 && P<500) ? P : 0;
}
void Persona::setEstatura(float E){
    estatura = (E>30 && E<280) ? E : 0;
}
string Persona::getNombre(void){
return nombre;
}
string Persona::getFechaNac(void){
    return fechaNac;
}
float Persona::getPeso(void){
    return peso;
}
float Persona::getEstatura(void){
    return estatura;
}
void Persona::mostrarDat(){
    cout << "\nNombre: " << getNombre();
    cout << "\nFecha de nacimiento: " << getFechaNac();
    cout << "\nPeso: " << getPeso() << " Kg";
    cout << "\nEstatura: " << getEstatura() << " Cm";
}
```

**"main.cpp":**

```
#include "Persona.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

Persona humano;

 cout << "\nConstructor default: ";
 humano.mostrarDat();

 humano.setNombre("Jose Ramon Garibay Alvarez");
 humano.setFechaNac("27 Octubre de 1989");
 humano.setPeso(80);
 humano.setEstatura(175.5);
 cout << "\n\nEstableciendo datos validos: ";
 humano.mostrarDat();

 humano.setNombre("Karina Nogueira Briseno");
 humano.setFechaNac("15 Agosto de 1985");
 humano.setPeso(0.457);
 humano.setEstatura(17);
 cout << "\n\nEstableciendo datos Invalidos: ";
 humano.mostrarDat();

 return 0;
 }
```

First of all i'm getting an error: http://oi40.tinypic.com/2v96quo.jpg
and i dont know if im doing right the "#including" files. I remember my profesor was using something like "#ifndef SOMETHING" but i don't know if it is necessary, Thanks for your answers! :)

Comment: For starters, change `#include <Persona.hpp>` to `#include "Persona.hpp"`. Second, the `#ifndef PERSONA_HEADER` is called a header guard (or include guard, or include fencepost, or a multitude of other names) and are used to protect against multiple inclusion of dependent headers. There are plenty of examples of proper use of it on this site. Do some searching on those terms.

Answer (score 2):

Use `#include "Persona.hpp"` instead of `#include <Persona.hpp>`

Comment: Trying replacing the <> for "" gives me another error: -------------- Build: Release in Persona (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)--------------- mingw32-g++.exe -o bin\Release\Persona.exe obj\Release\main.o obj\Release\Persona.o Persona.hpp.gch -s Persona.hpp.gch: file not recognized: File format not recognized collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) 0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))

Comment: @MrcRjs Since you're using precompiled headers (deactivate those if you're not sure what you're doing), make sure to clear/clean up your build directory at least once after making significant changes to your headers.

Comment: I set to default compiler options and deleted "persona.hpp.ghc" but sills being created and giving the building error :/

Comment: Check if http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php/topic,6108.msg46765.html#msg46765 fixes the precompiled header problem.

Comment: Wow thanks it worked! i just unchecked the "compile file" and "link" options. :D

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've got the wrong include directories set.

In addition, you're essentially including your header the "wrong" way, which might be the reason as well:

- `#include "header.h"`: Will look in your current code directory (i.e. where your cpp file is) first, when looking for that specific header file.
- `#include <header.h>`: Will look in your system/predefined include directories first.

However, based on your compiler('s) settings, it's version, etc. it's possible that there won't be any difference (unless you've got conflicting file names). It's definitely a good idea to always follow the intended route:

Use `#include "..."` to include header files that sit somewhere in your source directory. Use `#include <...>` to include other headers that should be installed on the machine where you're compiling (i.e. external dependencies).

---

The added note about include guards (either using `#ifndef`  and `#define` or `#pragma once`): Those should be used to prevent header files to be included more than once in the same translation unit, e.g. if the same header file is included by two different other headers, you'd end up with redefinitions of variables, structures, classes, etc.

Include guards are an easy way to prevent this behavior; you'll just have to make sure to use a macro that's unique enough.

A basic include guard could be something as simple as this:

```
#ifndef MY_CUSTOM_HEADER_FILE
#define MY_CUSTOM_HEADER_FILE
// Your header  file code
#endif
```

However, you might agree that this can be rather bothersome and theoretically error prone, e.g. if someone picks common words or names like `CUSTOMER` or `CUSTOMER_H`. Due to this, pretty much any modern preprocessor will accept the pragma instruction `#pragma once`. If that line is in a header file (and active), the compiler will ensure that it's never included more than once:

```
#pragma once

// Your header  file code
```

Comment: After changing <> for "" it gives me this error:    -------------- Build: Release in Persona (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

mingw32-g++.exe  -o bin\Release\Persona.exe obj\Release\main.o obj\Release\Persona.o Persona.hpp.gch  -s  
Persona.hpp.gch: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))

Comment: And ive already added  "#ifndef __PERSONA_HPP
#define __PERSONA_HPP" to Persona.hpp

Answer (score 0):

If you have different directories for source and header files, please be sure that you locate the correct directory. You might have to change the directory like that:

```
#include "../Headers/Persona.hpp"
```

Answer (score 0):

For better programming approach in OOPS always use #ifndef directive in your .h or .hpp file.
start your .hpp like this.

```
#ifndef __PERSONA_HPP
#define __PERSONA_HPP
```

and at the ending of your file put this line

```
#endif
```

This will take care of many thing and avoid including header file many time.

Answer (score 0):

> I remember my profesor was using something like "#ifndef SOMETHING" but i don't know if it is necessary,

`#ifndef` is a header guard. It is not what is causing your problem, but here's how to use them. You put them at the top of your header like this:

```
#ifndef SOMETHING_H
#define SOMETHING_H
```

and at the end of the header you put:

```
#endif
```

It basically means that each header gets included exactly once. If you don't have a header guard, you might run into problems.

For example, if you have `A.cpp` and `B.cpp` that both `#include "header.h"`, then when the compiler compiles the second one you will get a lot of errors along the lines of "such-and-such class is already defined" or "such-and-such variable is already defined".

But if you have a header guard then when it tries to include the header a second time the `#ifndef` will fail because `SOMETHING_H` will have been already defined (when it included the header the first time). So it will skip the whole file until it gets to the `#endif` and you won't be declaring variables multiple times.

This probably won't be a problem for you if you are only making small projects at the moment, but it is a strongly recommended habit to get into.